# INVALID_CREDENTIAL, 'Certificate object must be an object.') in firebase-admin node application

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

- `Operating System` version:  `Ubuntu 18.04`
- `Firebase SDK` version:  `5.13.1`
- `Firebase` Product: `firebase-admin`
- `Node.js` version: `10.9`
- `NPM` version: `6.2.0`

I am running node application in `ECS fargate` with above details.
Here, am getting following error

> throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL, 'Certificate object must be an object.');

The same docker images works in locally, but not `ECS fargate`.
not able

`Docker` file code as as follow

```
FROM node:10.9.0
LABEL maintainer="xxxxx"
RUN mkdir /usr/src/cx-xxx
WORKDIR  /usr/src/cx-xxx
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN pwd
RUN ls
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm install
# RUN npm audit fix
RUN npm run build
RUN ls

EXPOSE 3000
# RUN forever stopall && forever list

CMD [ "./node_modules/forever/bin/forever","dist/index.js" ]
```

Comment: You will need to show the code that is initializing the Firebase Admin SDK for us to be able to help here.

Comment: Thanks.. Figured out the issue.. Somehow my .env was not getting copied to fargate. once i fixed, works smoothly